# Zend Framework URI space encoding in PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, uri, encode

I've a Zend Framework URI like /controller/action/var1/value1/var2/value2 .

1. Value2 has a space character in it. How should I encode it in PHP? When I use urlencode with value2, this converts space into '+' instead of '%20f'. Is that ok?
2. This value2 is also added to a href location by javascript on client side. I'm using escape function there but when I click link I neither see '+' nor '%20f' in firefox address bar. Though when I see it in firebug 'net' tab, I see %20f.

Which functions should I use in PHP and javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your first question, that is the difference between [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) and [`rawurlencode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) :

```
var_dump(urlencode("hello, world"));
```

Will get you :

```
string 'hello%2C+world' (length=14)
```

While

```
var_dump(rawurlencode("hello, world"));
```

will get you :

```
string 'hello%2C%20world' (length=16)
```

I suppose both should be OK ; but feel free to give it a try, just in case ;-)

About the second point : Firefox tries to make URLs "prettier", displaying them in a human-readable way, instead of encoded -- which is bad for us developpers, but nice to end-users.

For instance, if I type this URL in Firefox's address bar :

```
http://tests/temp/temp.php?a=hello%2C%20world
```

When I press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, it's automatically translated to

```
http://tests/temp/temp.php?a=hello%2C%20world
```

If it works the way you are doing it *(and, as you are seeing an encoded URL with Firebug, it's probably working)*, everything's OK ;-)

Comment: I believe, though I'm not sure, that `%20` is more correct than `+` in the path portion of URLs.  Javascript's `escape()` function will give you very similar behavior to PHP's `rawurlencode()`, so I'd recommend using that on the JS side.

Comment: @pixor : for the sake of consistency, you are probably right :-)